# How to install Windows 10 on my laptop(Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I want to install Windows 10 on my HP with current Ubuntu OS.I have made USB bootable
[image]

I have change boot order on my BIOS but when I insert USB nothing happens,I was expecting installation process.What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm confused. Your screenshot is from Windows.

Comment: @Seth I have created bootable USB on my desktop,now I want to boot my HP 6830 laptop,which does not recognize USB(MBR partition scheme probably)

Comment: If you created the USB disk from Windows then I don't see how this is Ubuntu related at all. Consider asking over at [su] where Windows and hardware problems are on-topic.